# Event encoding in substrate pallet

Tags: pallet, rust, events

Can two pallets have exactly same event name and event parameters. If yes then is there a way to distinguish the event came from which pallet in golang.

Comment: For the Go part you can use [GSRPC](https://github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client) which has some issues but works for basic use-cases. [Example](https://github.com/perun-network/perun-polkadot-backend/blob/9ec28fc9fd9d89f715cdc991c0794e38746e6f19/pkg/substrate/event_source.go#L67).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, event name is superficial. What actually matters is how the pallet event is encoded into bytes.

Pallet events are encoded such that the first byte represents the pallet index, and the second byte represents the event index. Pallet index is determined by the ordering or explicit numbering in the `construct_runtime!` macro, and event index is determined by the ordering in the Event enum.

Here is a minimal example:

```rust
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        Pallet1: pallet_example::<Instance1>,
        Pallet2: pallet_example::<Instance2>,
    }
);
```

You can see in this example, we are actually using the exact same pallet twice in our runtime via pallet instancing. Thus, these two pallet instances will have all of the exact same events, parameters, and even functions.

The way we distinguish these two, is that we also prepend the encoded bytes with the pallet index first.

So the second event (index 1) of `Pallet1` will be encoded as `0x0101`, whereas the same event in `Pallet2` will be encoded as `0x0201`.

The same can be said for extrinsics, errors, and other "aggregated" types.